# Aspose VB Fill in Table in Template Datatable

Tags: vb.net, templates, aspose

I want to fill a Datatable in a TableStart / TableEnd region. But i fill my datatable with a loop

```
Dim Dt = new DataTable()
Dt.TableName ="MyRegion"
Dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
Dt.Columns.Add("Age", GetType (String))

Dim row As DataRow
For Each item In Items
row = Dt.NewRow()
row("Name") = item.Name
row("Age") = item.Age
Dt.Rows.Add(row)
Next

MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dt)
```

My template is 
TableStart:MyRegion
<>   <>
TableEnd:MyRegion

I get a doc file but here are more tables. But I want only one table with good distance between rows.

Can same one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the TableStart field in the first cell of row and TableEnd field in the last cell of row. Please check the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EUUQ.jpg).

Follow these simple rules when marking a region:

- TableStart and TableEnd fields must be inside the same section in the
  document.
- If used inside a table, TableStart and TableEnd must be
  inside the same row in the table.
- Mail merge regions can be nested inside each other.
- Mail merge    regions should be well formed (there is always a pair
  of matching    TableStart and TableEnd with the same table name).

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.